Generating an XMLDsig manually in .NET (without using SignedXml)
I have an XML file, that needs to be signed by an external service, which expects a hash of the data and returns the signature value and the signing certificate (contains only the public key). I need to generate an XAdES file with the data and the signature, but I am struggling to even create a valid XMLDsig file. The SignedXml class basically does all of that, but since the signing happens on the API and not by calling ComputeSignature(), it's useless for me.
Are there any external tools or libraries that could correctly canonicalize, transform and generate the transformed SignedInfo object that could be sent to an API for signing?
I used the "xsd.exe" tool and generated XMLDsig and XAdES classes from their schemes and tried to initialize these objects manually, canonicalize, transform and sign, but the xml signature always comes out invalid. When I make a really simple test file and compare the manually created digest of a reference to the one generated by SignedXml, it's always different. I guess there is something wrong with the canonicalization or the transforming.
